# Selenium ImeActivationFailedException and ImeNotAvailableException

Tags: java, selenium, exception, webdriver, ime

While reading [selenium common exceptions](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/common/selenium.common.exceptions.html), I came across below two exceptions.

```
exception selenium.common.exceptions.ImeActivationFailedException
(msg=None, screen=None, stacktrace=None)
Thrown when activating an IME engine has failed.

exception selenium.common.exceptions.ImeNotAvailableException
(msg=None, screen=None, stacktrace=None)
Thrown when IME support is not available. This exception is thrown for every IME-related method call if IME support is not available on the machine.
```

a. What is the meaning of IME engine?

b. When does below exceptions will occur? What kind of cleanup code do we need to write in **Finally** block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to my answer about IME in the below link:

[What exactly does ime() in selenium do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588441/what-exactly-does-ime-in-selenium-do/35068710#35068710)

When you `ImeActivationFailedException` and `ImeNotAvailableException` these exceptions, **you are not able to input desired (Chinese/Japanese/etc) characters** in your test webpage, and hence it is advised to fail the test with appropriate message.